# Number of even palindromes by concatenating two strings

Tags: string, palindrome

This problem popped into my mind.

I have two strings `s1` and `s2`, each with say, a maximum length of about 500 characters. How many sub-sequences of `s1+s2` (concatenation of `s1` and `s2`) are even palindromes, with the first half of the palindrome being a sub-sequence of `s1` and the second half being a sub-sequence of `s2`?

Of course the brute-force solution would be to find the number of pairs of sub-sequences of s1 and s2 where one is the reverse of the other. But with a length of about 500, this is too time consuming.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried brute force? There are at most (n-1) substrings of length n that cross the s1-s2 boundry (and less than that for longer sub-strings). So there would be only a few tens of thousands of strings to check, which should be almost instantaneous on a modern cpu.

Comment: @JamesK I took it as asking about *noncontiguous* palindromes: the part in s1 and the part in s2 don't have to extend to the boundary. Still -- brute force is just quadratic, which is trivial with 1000 chars